# What format is this geometry and how to convert it into a shapefile?

Tags: shapefile, geometry, convert

I recieved geometries in this format:
{2007,25832,null,{1,1003,1},{614250.44763045,5311487.72371873,611209.43848971,... 5311287.72301873}}

Does anyone know what format this is and how I can convert the geometries into a shapefile?

Comment: looks like custom json.  Where did you get the data from, perhaps they have more detail of the structure

Comment: I might hazard a guess that `25832` is an EPSG code ~ https://epsg.org/crs_25832/ETRS89-UTM-zone-32N.html and `614250.44763045,5311487.72371873,611209.43848971`... are easting/northing values

Answer (score 3):

This is the format from [Oracle Spatial SDO_Geometry](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SPATL/sdo_geometry-object-type.htm#SPATL490) the data is organized this way:

{SDO_GTYPE, SDO_SRID,SDO_POINT,SDO_ELEM_INFO[],SDO_ORDINATES[]}